# Is it possible to match faces in the images which are stored in the firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, mlvision

In my flutter application, I want to implement facial recognition feature like this.... The image will be uploaded using image picker and the face in this image should be compared with the images that are already there in firebase. If there are any matches found, all the matching images should be displayed and a success message should be returned.

Is it possible to implement this kind of feature using MLVision in Flutter?

If so, please provide detailed explanation or some sources to learn more about this implementation.

Thank You!!

Answer (score 1):

With `MLVision` in Flutter and `TensorFlow Lite` Flutter you can compare and search for similar images in your database by comparing similarity & dissimilarities.

You can check out [this blog](https://www.hidigital.io/blog/2020/10/face-recognition-authentication-using-flutter-and-tensorflow-lite) for detailed implementation.

Here is a real life implementation of this -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOE5C.gif